# What is the name of a dip net with solid metal mesh/bowl?

Tags: fishing

My dad likes to use dip nets to catch escaped crabs when we drop one, but likes the ones with a solid metal mesh or bowl.

I know such a thing exists because we have an old rusty one full of holes and our neighbor also has one. The type of net I'm looking for does not have the mesh/bowl collapse and is pretty much non flexible. Every time I search for such a net on the internet though, I cannot find anything close to what I'm looking for.

In case I'm using the wrong terminology, here is a picture of the kind of net I'm looking for.
[image]

The bowl of the net here keeps its shape and doesn't droop or anything when turned sideways.

What do I need to google to find nets similar to this? All searches by me, my mom, and my sister have all failed so far. Any time we search for anything metal we only find metal poles and not metal bowls.

Comment: Amazon UK has [chicken wire crab net](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Hurricane-Ring-Wire-Crab-18-Inch/dp/B0010FXPQA). The search terms **chicken wire net** turned up quite a lot of possibilities really. Perhaps you could make your own too.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that sometimes they're called "wire crab net" and sometimes just "crab net". The problem is possibly that you're looking for dip nets which are soft, the specific crab nets are often wire mesh.

I'm also getting a few sets of instructions to build your own in the results.